# MySQL Where Not Exists

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

What's wrong with this code? I keep getting `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax`

```
SELECT clientReport.id
  WHERE clientReport.rowNumber NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT clientReport.rowNumber FROM report02, clientReport
      WHERE report02.id=clientReport.id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to do something like:

```
SELECT clientReport.id 
FROM clientReport 
LEFT JOIN report02 ON(report02.id = clientReport.id)
WHERE report02.id is null;
```

This will return all IDs from clientReport which have no corresponding entry in report02.

An alternative might be:

```
SELECT clientReport.id FROM clientReport
WHERE clientReport.rowNumber NOT IN (
  SELECT clientReport.rowNumber 
  FROM report02, clientReport
  WHERE report02.id=clientReport.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `FROM` on your first select statement:

```
SELECT clientReport.id
  FROM clientReport '<--- need this
  WHERE clientReport.rowNumber NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT clientReport.rowNumber FROM report02, clientReport
      WHERE report02.id=clientReport.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the full error message MySQL server is returning?  You should get an error message like the below:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax near `NOT EXISTS`
```

You should also consider using a RIGHT JOIN instead of a sub-query select, as a RIGHT JOIN seems to be what you want in this case.

EDIT:  Additionally, because of the performance hit observed when sub-queries are run, it's advisabe to use very selective JOINs instead, that being said, it will be okay to use sub-queries again in normal queries when MySQL GA implements the use of LIMIT in sub-queries.  This will reduce the performance hit greatly.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add from clause in main query.

```
SELECT clientReport.id from clientReport
  WHERE clientReport.rowNumber NOT IN (
    SELECT clientReport.rowNumber FROM report02, clientReport
      WHERE report02.id=clientReport.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS`